# How to use WHERE Clause in Cypher/Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have built this database on Neo4j

[image]

I'm trying to find the actors that played in movies in which Keanu Reeves also played. My code is:

```
MATCH (a:Actor)-[r:ACTS_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE (m:Movie)<-[r:ACTS_IN]-(:Actor { name:"Keanu Reeves" })
RETURN a.name
```

But it doesn't work. I'm new to this language and I'm not even sure if I should use WHERE or WITH or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** find the list of movies that Keanu acted in.

**Second:** `WITH` Keanu and the each of movies find the other actors in those movies that aren't Keanu.

**Third:** return the distinct list of Keanu's colleagues with which he acted across the list of movies

```
match (k:Actor {name: 'Keanu Reeves'})-[r:ACTS_IN]->(m:Movie)
with k,m
match (m)<-[:ACTS_IN]-(colleague:Actor)
where colleague <>  k
return distinct(colleague)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your query uses the same identifier, `r`, in the `MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses. That means the 2 `ACTS_IN` relationships are supposed to be identical. Therefore, `a` will always be the node for `Keanu Reeves`.

This form of your query should return all relevant actors (including Keanu), but would probably not be very performant:

```
MATCH (a:Actor)-[r:ACTS_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE (m)<-[:ACTS_IN]-(:Actor { name:"Keanu Reeves" })
RETURN DISTINCT a.name;
```

This query should be faster (and eliminate Keanu from the result), especially if you first create an index on `:Actor(name)`:

```
MATCH (a:Actor)-[:ACTS_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTS_IN]-(:Actor { name:"Keanu Reeves" })
RETURN DISTINCT a.name;
```